# Instagram graph api get amount of follows and followers

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Trying to figure out a way to get the amount of follows and followers of a user via the Instagram-basic-display-api which is intended for consumer users.
I can only get the `account_type, id, media_count, username` 
fields when doing a get on the user node

```
GET https://graph.instagram.com/{user-id}
  ?fields={fields}
  &access_token={access-token}
```

Since the old Basic Instagram api https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_self supported the amount of follows and followers Im wondering if they are going to add this or if this is possible via another new Instagram endpoint?